# Laravel 5.0 get redis data to the node on socket emit from front end without ajaxcall and update in mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, laravel, redis, socket.io

Am working on a project where every user will input something and that will emit through socket to the node, and will broadcast to the other users who are connected. Now i need this to update in redis and mysql. Help me how to achieve this. Need to fire an event in laravel everytime when user do something from node avoiding ajax calls. And how should i keep sync both redis and mysql when event fires.

Comment: Please do some research and return once you have a real problem and you can show us some code and what you have done so far to fix it.

Comment: I thought i ll get answer not suggestion, all i want is to update redis and mysql from node without using ajax calls

Comment: I got this to working on artisan command now i can subscribe to a channel and write some mysql queries in it, but publishing it to redis is not working need some help here.